# SQL - distinct on column a for every value in one column b

Tags: sql, group-by, distinct

I'm working with a table called `du_vertrag`, and I'm trying to build a query that selects distinct values for `id` and `status` pairs.

Input Table:

| id | status | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6251899 | beantragt | 20201008 |
| 6377042 | beantragt | 20201008 |
| 6387891 | beantragt | 20201008 |
| 6251899 | übergabe | 20201009 |
| 6377042 | übergabe | 20201009 |
| 6387891 | übergabe | 20201009 |
| 6251899 | übergabe | 20201010 |
| 6377042 | übergabe | 20201010 |
| 6387891 | übergabe | 20201010 |
| 6251899 | aktiv | 20201024 |
| 6377042 | aktiv | 20201024 |
| 6387891 | aktiv | 20201024 |

Desired Output:

| id | status | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6251899 | beantragt | 20201008 |
| 6377042 | beantragt | 20201008 |
| 6387891 | beantragt | 20201008 |
| 6251899 | übergabe | 20201009 |
| 6377042 | übergabe | 20201009 |
| 6387891 | übergabe | 20201009 |
| 6251899 | aktiv | 20201024 |
| 6377042 | aktiv | 20201024 |
| 6387891 | aktiv | 20201024 |

I need for every id the new status with the first datetime the status changed.

Comment: Use `distinct` if you want unique rows. Use `group by` if you want to aggregate (`min`, `max`, `sum` etc). I don't know what you get in your query, most databases would throw an error. Please share some sample data, so we get an idea what's going on

Comment: But I've put the query + output in the description?! i don't know what else I could provide to describe my problem better

Comment: then you already have your output as your very input table, what's the point of this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need distinct values for each "*id*" and "*status*", you can aggregate over  those two fields and select the minimum date to get your output:

```
SELECT id, 
       status, 
       MIN(date) AS date
FROM du_vertrag 
GROUP BY id, 
         status
```

If you can share what your DBMS is, I can link a fiddle where you can test this solution.

Comment: Also this sample is not representative of your original table as the query in the answer works for the data you shared. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hAZWCfzQhoG3dJwuZSSiSq/0

Comment: Anyways, I'd suggest using the DATE data type instead of the VARCHAR to indicate dates and avoid potential comparison issues.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be simple *aggregation*

```
select id, status, min(date) as date
from du_vertrag
group by id, status;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *
FROM (SELECT id, status,
row_number() over (partition by id, status order by date asc) as row_num
FROM du_vertrag) d
where d.row_num = 1