# SQL - distinct on column x for every value in one column y

Tags: sql, group-by, distinct

I'm working with a table called `du_vertrag`, and I'm trying to build a query that selects distinct values for `id` and `status` pairs.

| id | status | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6251899 | beantragt | 20201008 |
| 6377042 | beantragt | 20201008 |
| 6387891 | beantragt | 20201008 |
| 6251899 | übergabe | 20201009 |
| 6377042 | übergabe | 20201009 |
| 6387891 | übergabe | 20201009 |
| 6251899 | übergabe | 20201010 |
| 6377042 | übergabe | 20201010 |
| 6387891 | übergabe | 20201010 |
| 6251899 | aktiv | 20201024 |
| 6377042 | aktiv | 20201024 |
| 6387891 | aktiv | 20201024 |

Desired Output:

| id | status | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6251899 | beantragt | 20201008 |
| 6377042 | beantragt | 20201008 |
| 6387891 | beantragt | 20201008 |
| 6251899 | übergabe | 20201009 |
| 6377042 | übergabe | 20201009 |
| 6387891 | übergabe | 20201009 |
| 6251899 | aktiv | 20201024 |
| 6377042 | aktiv | 20201024 |
| 6387891 | aktiv | 20201024 |

I need for every id the new status with the first datetime the status changed.

Comment: You [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72687304/sql-distinct-on-column-a-for-every-value-in-one-column-b) this before, and accepted an answer. That answer is the same you got now, what was wrong with it?